# Set Properties via runtime for Multiple Controls

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I have a form that contains about 25 Buttons. I want to set the same property for the Multiple buttons based on user input. The properties i want to change are,

- Button text
- Button Fore Color
- Button Back Color
- Button Size

I have been able to do this using code but the Code is long. I want to know if there is a way to loop to change all of them.

This is what i used

```
    button1.Text = btntext;
    button1.ForeColor = btnforecolor;
    button1.BackColor = btnbackcolor;
    button1.Size = new Size(btnwidth, btnheight);
```

I had to do this like this for the 25 button, i want to know if there is any better way to do this with less code??..

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options here:

1) Create a list of buttons and loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++){
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Text = ...
    btn.Location = new Point(10 + (i%5)*100, (i/5)*30);
    btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);              // TODO: Implement btn_Click event
    this.Controls.Add(btn);
}
```

2) Loop through your existing controls:

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls) {
    Button btn = c as Button;
    if (btn == null) continue;
    btn.Text = ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks.Your second option worked perfectly, the first worked too but i had problems with the arrangement.

Comment: @ElizabethAmesin: For the arrangement you have only the counter `i`, therefore you have to calculate the buttons location. Please see my edit for a example.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't iterate through all of the buttons on a form but need a specific list of buttons I use this code.

```
List<Button> ListOfButtons = new List<Button>
    {
          this.Button1,
          this.Button2,
    }


foreach (Button myButton in ListOfButtons)
    {
           //Do your assigments to myButton

    }
```